# Kunena add "# post to next rank" below users informations?

Tags: joomla-2.5, kunena

Is it possibile to add the number of posts you need to get next rank in Kunena?

Something like this maybe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4920.png

I was trying to do this with AlphaUserPoints but I actually can't find an AlphaUserPoints' download link for Joomla 2.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm going to give this +1 as I actually think it's a very good question, however, are you trying to do this for Kunena **or** Alpha User Points? Either one, have you tried anything of your own so far?

Comment: Thank you Lodder. I thought about this yesterday and I was going to try this with AlphaUserPoints (on my Kunena Forum) but on the Official website of AUP there's only the download link for joomla 3.x and higher. Sadly, I still have joomla 2.5 so I can't try it, yet.

Comment: I knew AlphaUsersPoints can be integrated in Kunena but I'd like to add this feature to KUNENA.